# How to fix 'cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in' error in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to create Country and State Dropdown with AJAX, I followed a series on youtube but I'm getting an error.
when I choose a country from the first dropdown,
at first it shows me nothing in the dropdown of the city but when I added `JSON.parse(data)` instead of `data` in the [ $.each instruction ] it shows `[object object]` and not the name of the city.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('select[name="country"]').on('change', function(){
            var country_id = $(this).val();

            if(country_id){

                $.ajax({
                    url:'/getcities/'+country_id,
                    type:'GET',
                    data:'json',
                    success:function(data){
                        console.log(data);

                        $('select[name="city"]').empty();
                        $.each(data, function(key, value){
                            $('select[name="city"]').append('<option value="'+key+'">'+ value + '</option>');
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                $('select[name="city"]').empty();
            }


             });
    });
```

this is the blade of country dropdown :

```html
<select class="form-control" name="country">
                                                    <option selected>
                                                       Choose your country
                                                    </option>
                                                    @if($countries->count() > 0)
                                                        @foreach($countries as $country)
                                                            <option value="{{ $country->id }}"
                                                                    >{{ $country->value }}</option>
                                                        @endforeach
                                                    @endif
                                                </select>
```

this is the blade of city dropdown :

```html
<select class="form-control" name="city">
                                                    <option value="" selected>
                                                       Choose your city
                                                    </option>

                                                </select>
```

I'm using Laravel for retrieving the data from the database.

Comment: We can't help iterate or parse data we can't see. Provide a sample of the actual response as per [mcve]

Comment: @Belhedi Rafaa can you put this in a fiddle or stackblitz...

Comment: @eugen I can't it's related with a controller and database using laravel

Comment: ```$.each(JSON.parse(data), function(key, value){
                            $('select[name="city"]').append('<option value="'+key+'">'+ value + '</option>');
                        });```Have you tried to use JSON.parse on data in each?

Comment: That edit doesn't have anything to do with the JSON response of the ajax request where you are actually having problems

Comment: @eugen yeah i tried and it shows me [object object] instead of the name of the city

Comment: So you need the property of `value` object that contains the name string ... something like `value.name`. Again...hard to help with what we can't see

Comment: @BelhediRafaa actually you should do it the other way around in your ajax instead of data use -->   dataType: "json"  and leave the JSON.parse. it would be good to see a sample of your json data